# Playing as a revenant

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

I got really intrigued by the idea of playing as a revenant but my googlefu failed me when i tried to find how much Vitae they produce each day. Are there any books or sources that determine how much Vitae a revenant produces each day?

Comment: For more info you can check out the VTM V20 book Ghouls & Revenants.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of the edition of WoD, Revenants produce one blood point per day. However, you must remember that they are still limited to the max of their ghoul blood pool that is 2 + 1 for each century they live to the max of 10 blood points.